# Gatsby: Skipped not serializable cache item 'mini-css-extract-plugin

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, tailwind-css

I updated tailwind v2 to v3. Also using gatsby which I'm quite new.
And I didn't have this two warnings when it's tailwind v2. But I get this in v3. I see some some kind of solution in webpack.config.js like updating latest autoprefixer but not in gatsby. So I'm not sure how to solve it.
I would appreciate if you could give me some advice. Thank you.

```
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Skipped not serializable cache item 'mini-css-extract-plugin /Users/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??
ruleSet[1].rules[9].oneOf[1].use[1]!/Users//node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[9].oneOf[1].use[2]!/Users/src/styles.css|0|
Compilation/modules|/Users/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??
ruleSet[1].rules[9].oneOf[1].use[1]!/Users/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??
ruleSet[1].rules[9].oneOf[1].use[2]!/Users/src/styles.css': No serializer registered for Warning
<w> while serializing webpack/lib/cache/PackFileCacheStrategy.PackContentItems ->
 webpack/lib/NormalModule -> Array { 1 items } ->
```

- What I use

```
"gatsby": "^3.13.0",
"gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud": "^3.2.0",
"tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
"postcss": "^8.4.12",
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, did you find a resolution for this?

Comment: For me, once I removed all other warning from gatsby, the above error simply disappeared.

Comment: Try to add `postcss-reporter` plugin to postcss.config.js, as the last plugin in the chain. That gave me a clear warning message to the console, naming the root cause.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue and it turned out it was because I was using the `start` value to align some items in flex elements.

For example, the following code caused the warning:

```
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: start;
    gap: 20px;
}
```

I changed the `justify-content` value to **`flex-start`** and the warning disappeared.

```
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This makes me question several things I thought I knew about how all this works, but I got the same error for an `align-items` set to `start` instead of `flex-start`.

Comment: I was facing the same and changing `start` to `flex-start` was the solution. Just realized that `start` wasn't one of the values for `justify-content`. In my case, I was using bootstrap with SCSS Modules

Comment: Do you know why this problem happens?

Comment: Also similarly "end" needs to be "flex-end"

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a CSS warning generated by the `tailwindcss` plugin, which cannot be reported correctly, because `postcss-reporter` isn't setup in the right way. Apparently `postcss-report` should be placed last in the plugin chain. I found it difficult to find documentation to do that right, too. This config is working for me:

```js
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    'postcss-reporter': {
      clearReportedMessages: true,
    },
  },
};
```

This way the problem in the CSS is reported with colorization and formatting, instead of the warning about serialization, to the development log in the terminal.

(Gatsby 5, Postcss 8, TailwindCSS 3.3)